# normalize command before calling exec/spawn on windows?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I'm trying to call ffmpeg from the current directory. On linux I'd call `exec` or `spawn` with `'./ffmpeg'`. In order for this code to be portable to windows do I need to strip off the `'./'` or is that somehow taken care of for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just half an answer: welcome to anyone to modify it and expand it.

Here is the result of my digging in the [source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js):

The `exec` method does a small check of the platform (taken from the source):

```
if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    file = 'cmd.exe';
    args = ['/s', '/c', '"' + command + '"'];
    options = util._extend({}, options);
    options.windowsVerbatimArguments = true;
  } else {
    file = '/bin/sh';
    args = ['-c', command];
  }
```

I don't know how you have added `ffmpeg` to your PATH on Windows, so it really depends on your setup. In any case, simply pass to `exec` the command as if you would be running it from the `cmd.exe` shell.

I however could not find something similar for `spawn`.